# Swapping scene in a static method?

Tags: java, javafx, controller

I need to change scene in a static method. I am trying these codes:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/AdPage.fxml"));
Main.getMainStage().setScene(new Scene(root));
```

Since getClass() method is not static, this code cannot be compiled. What can I do?

Comment: Apart from the obvious "don't use a static method for this", you can do `ClassName.class` in place of `getClass()`, where `ClassName` is the name of the class this code is in.

Comment: Why "dont use a static method for this"

Comment: I have a static method which shows a gridpane and in that gridpane there are buttons. When button is clicked, scene will be updated. Method is static because it must be used by other classes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is controller behavior, so making it static greatly reduces your ability to reuse it (imagine you wanted two or more instances of whatever this does in the same application...). (In general, I would consider the only use of  static in a UI application, other than constants, to be something that only very advanced programmers should do, when they are certain the know what they are doing.) So typically you should make this an instance method and share an instance of the class with whichever objects need access to it. But it's your application - you can do it whatever way you want.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/41285805/2189127 for another approach to something similar.